# Do we need to re-factor Microserivces

Tags: asynchronous, microservices, amqp, messagebroker

We have created our application based on Microservice architecture and contains about 30 Microservices. Almost all inter-service communications is synchronous and they call each other directly.

Now we want to have loosly coupled services and having eventual consistency by having RabbitMQ and use asynchronouse communication pattern.

Do we need to re-factor all services or there is a smart way to achieve asynchronous communication without refactoring our servcies?

Comment: You may have to refactor your services. I don't see any other way that you can integrate message broker without touching your code.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change some amount of your services, at least where they exchange information, and break the synchrony of them. But just how much refactoring that entails is very difficult to say without seeing the details of how your system is architected now.